# Threejs ray cast get coordinate of intersection

Tags: javascript, three.js

So, I have a plane, and I got raycast set up. What I want to do is get the coordinate of the intersection on the plane, thanks.

(Note: the color change is just to test if the raycast was actually working.)

Here is my code :

```
      raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

      //calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

      for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

        intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );

      }
```

Cheers, Keegan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `Raycaster`, the value `intersects[ i ].point` is a `Vector3()` representing the world coordinates of the point of intersection.

Inspect `intersects[ i ]` in the console to see what else is returned.

three.js r.72

Comment: When I use the alert function with "intersects[ i ].points" , I receive the following, "[object Object]".